# running multiple clang passes

Tags: clang, llvm-clang

I have been using `Tool.run(ToolAction)` to run a clang tool. If I want to run multiple tools on the same input source, do I just create different `ToolAction`s and call `Tool.run` one after another? Or do I somehow chain the `ASTFrontendAction`s together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you want to achieve.

If you want to parse once, and then do multiple things with AST you should better implement multiple ASTConsumers.

Then you can create aggregate ASTConsumer:

```
class AggregateASTConsumer : public clang::ASTConsumer {

public:
    void HandleTranslationUnit(clang::ASTContext& Ctx) override {
         for (auto consumer: consumers)
              consumer.HandleTranslationUnit(Ctx);

    }
    std::vector<ASTConsumer*> consumers;
}
```

But if you want to re-parse input source code with some different options then you should run tool multiple times.

Comment: can you elaborate on how to actually chain the diverse consumers?
I have been using different matchers and been running them from the same tool until I found, that when calling clangTool.run for the second time,the references i held to nodes from the previous pass were lost.
now i don't know wether to use multiple tools or how I could make those matcherFinders to work on the same ast?

Comment: Instead of implementing `AggregateASTConsumer` yourself, use `clang::MultiplexConsumer` from `clang/Frontend/MultiplexConsumer.h`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a `ClangTool` named `Tool` and two `MatchFinder`s called `MatchFinder1` and `MatchFinder2` (with the appropriate matchers already added), the straightforward transformation is:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<ASTUnit>> ASTs;
Tool.buildASTs(ASTs);

for(auto& ast : ASTs) {
    // First pass
    MatchFinder1.matchAST(ast->getASTContext());
    // Second pass
    MatchFinder2.matchAST(ast->getASTContext());
}
```

This way, the AST nodes remain valid between the different matcher runs and can be correctly compared against each other.

Note that `FrontendAction` is not used at all with this approach, but to be honest I'm not completely sure what it actually *does*.